# Instance variables and functions

Tags: python

I made a post here [functions and class attributes (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086558/functions-and-class-attributes-python)

When you define
a class attribute and gave it a function like this:

**example 1**

```
def add_age(cls,age):
    cls.yrs_old = age
    return cls


class Test:
    age = add_age

a = Test()
a.age(5)


print(a.yrs_old)
```

`self` is automatically passed as the first argument of the `add_age` function.

However toying around with it more doing the same thing 
but this time passing the function as an instance attribute like this:

**example 2**

```
def test_func(self):
    self.class_attribute = "test"



class Test:
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func


a = Test(test_func)

print(a.func())
```

Answers in the linked post stated that all `functions` in the `class` are automatically passed a `self` if the `class` is instantiated like this:

```
a = Test(test_func)
```

Now what's strange here is had I put `test_func` in a class attribute it works just like my very first example.

If you pass the function in the constructor/init like this:

```
def test_func(self):
    self.class_attribute = "test" 

class Test:
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
```

and call it like this:

```
a = Test(test_func)

print(a.func())
```

`a.func` is suddenly acting like a static method as opposed to **example 1** where the function defined inside the class attribute becomes a regular class method.

What's going on?.

I thought all functions within a class are implicitly passed a `self` argument.

Answer (score 3):

After the body of the class statement is evaluated, the metaclass wraps each function in a descriptor which takes care of the distinction between instance, class, and static methods. When you assign the function to an *instance* attribute, you bypass that machinery, so that the attribute refers to a plain function object.

Comment: just like a `@staticmethod` right?. Im fairly new to python just a couple of months. so i'll have to look up **metaclass** and **descriptors**  thanks for you input

Comment: @Zion Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) to get started with Python metaclasses.

Comment: @That1Guy funny enough I did just that before you recommended it. that 3000+ upvoted answer was pretty sweet. it made me understand it a bit. bit  I can't figure out how to implement the metaclass. I literally tried copy pasting the code just to see how it works but. it doesn't work. 

I copy/pasted the example he gave with turning all your attribute names uppercase but it doesn't work on my `IDLE`

Comment: @Zion I wouldn't worry about metaclasses for a long time. In my experience, only about 1% of the metclasses that are written are needed. And only 1% of those are done correctly anyway.

Comment: @That1Guy I dunno. I like to learn python deeper and eventually make a framework one day.  plus I have this Obsessive Compulsive need to understand something I can't!. but yeah thanks though. I'll look around more for more info on metaclasses.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

> Any function object that is a class attribute defines a method for instances of that class. It is not necessary that the function definition is textually enclosed in the class definition: assigning a function object to a local variable in the class is also ok.

This means that only methods that are assigned to classes are instance methods for the instances of the class.

Example -

```
>>> class A:
...     def a(self):
...             print("Hmm")
...
>>> b = A()
>>> b.a()
Hmm
>>> b.a
<bound method A.a of <__main__.A object at 0x006D13D0>>
```

But as soon as you assign a separate function object to the instance variable, it is no longer an instance method , since is is not defined at the class level, it is only defined for that particular instance , Example -

```
>>> def c():
...     print("Hello")
...
>>> b.a = c
>>> b.a()
Hello
>>> b.a
<function c at 0x0017B198>
```

As you can see, when you directly assigned the function to the instance variable (instead of assigning it to class variable , it is now a normal instance attribute, that references a function object, and not an instance method.

You can also assign functions to class variables after the definition of class , and the instances would automatically get them as instance methods, Example -

```
>>> class A:
...     def a(self):
...             print("Hmm")
...
>>> def c(a):
...     print("Hello - ", a)
...
>>> b = A()
>>> A.b = c
>>> b.b
<bound method A.c of <__main__.A object at 0x006D13D0>>
>>> b.b()
Hello  <__main__.A object at 0x006D13D0>
```